# Checking if a value is in the db many times

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table A, with just two columns: 'id' and 'probably'. I need to go over a long list of ids, and determine for each one whether he is in A and has probability of '1'. What is the best way to do it?

I figured that it would be best to have 1 big query from A in the beginning of the script, and after that when I loop each id, I check the first query. but than i realized I don't know how to do that (efficiently). I mean, is there anyway to load all results from the first query to one array and than do in_array() check? I should mention that the first query should had few results, under 10 (while table A can be very large).

The other solution is doing a separate query in A for each id while I loop them. But this seems not very efficient...

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify: You have a list of `id`s in e.g. `$ids` and you want those that **are** in the table with probability 1 or those, which **are not** in the table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the initial list of ids in array, you can use the php **implode** function like this:

```
$query = "select id 
          from A
          where id in (".implode (',', $listOfIds).")
          and probability = 1";
```

Now you pass the string as first parameter of **mysql_query** and receive the list of ids with probability = 1 that are within your initial list.

Comment: +1 as long as you've already sanitized the array $listOfIds to ensure that they are of type (int) to avoid an injection attack.

Comment: looks like a smart solution... the only question is what if the list of ids is big, something like 500+ records?

Comment: @TerryE. True, but that always depends on how you created the content of the array.

Comment: @Moshe_Shaham. Then the string will grow. If I am not mistaken there isn't a limitation in PHP for a string

Comment: @doctore, if the list is big then this is still the most efficient way of querying MySQL: one query with a result set of 500+ rows.  If you start to hit limits then you can always add an extra loop to do this in N element, say 200 id, slices.

Comment: @TerryE. How to split the query is not an easy question to answer. An important aspect that affects performance is the communication php-mysql and greater the number of querys, more influence this factor. When it's best to launch multiple queries or when better to bring it all at one time will depend on doing some testing and see how they behave when establish parts with: 100, 200, 300 etc.. ids. Moreover, although the initial list may have 500 ids, doesn't mean that all are probability = 1

Comment: @doctore, spliting the query is easy: [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).  Each SQL query does have an overhead, but, say, 5 queries instead of 1,000 will run a lot faster.  If you don't then you risk randomly hitting some query or buffer limit.

Comment: @TerryE. I knew I didn't explain very well. I know how to split a query or an array, that is very simple. The problem is knowing how many parts: 1.2, ..., 10. To a good approximation of that number, some tests are necessary because there is no "global rule" to know it.

Comment: @doctore, the trick is not to fix the no of parts.  Chose an N which works on your server. IIRC, **max_allowed_packet** is the first constraint that you'll bump against. Why not pick something like 1,000?  OK, most times you'll only do one query, but if you do 2 or 10 is the runtime going to be that different if you'd used 5,000?

Answer (score 2):

```
// $skip the amount of results you wish to skip over
// $limit the max amount of results you wish to return
function returnLimitedResultsFromTable($skip=0, $limit=10) {

    // build the query
    $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `A` WHERE `probability`=1 LIMIT $skip, $limit";

    // store the result of the query
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    // if the query returned rows
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // while there are rows in $result
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            // populate results array with each row as an associative array
            $results[] = $row;
        }
        return $results;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

for each time you call this function you would need to increment skip by ten in order to retrieve the next ten results.
Then to use the values in the $results array (for example to print them):

```
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    print "$key => $value <br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Build a comma separated list with your ids and run a query like

```
SELECT id 
  FROM A 
  WHERE id IN (id1, id2, id3, ... idn) 
    AND probability = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first solution proposal states that:

1. You will query the table A, probabyly using `limit` clause since A is a table with large data.
2. You will place the retrieved data in an array.
3. You will iterate through the array to look for the id's with probability of '1'.
4. You will repeat the first three steps several times until table A is iterated fully.

**That is very inefficient!**

Algorithm described above would require lots of database access and unneccessary memory (for the temporary array). Instead, just use a select statement with 'WHERE' clause and process with the data you want.

You need a query like the following I suppose:

```
SELECT id, probably FROM A WHERE A.probably = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly, you should filter in the SQL query

> SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.probably = 1